# Remove specific field from model before creating after processing laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to make a trait for storing images for models. I am not able to remove the `thumbnail` from the model.

Is there any way to remove the thumbnail field from the model because there is no field like a thumbnail in the table?

```
trait ModelHelpers
{
protected static $thumbnail;

public static function boot()
{


       parent::boot();

        self::creating(function($model){
            $collection = collect($model);
            self::$thumbnail = $collection->only('thumbnail');
            $collection->except(['thumbnail']);
            $model->ignoreField('thumbnail');
            // ... code here
        });
    }
}
```

OR

Is there any way to add the data in the model that don't process while `mysql query` but is available in the model for processing before or after creating?

Right now I am adding the `thumbnail` key in fillable to get into the model but it is processed while the `insert` query that i don't want to:

```
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'title', 'meta_title', 'slug', 'summary', 'published','published_time', 'thumbnail'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`$fillbale` is used to define the properties you want to use in inserting.

If you want to skip some properties to insert it, you must use `$guarded`